# How can I audit who consume message from a sqs queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a sqs queue deployed in AMS and I'd like to know how consumed messages from the queue. When looking at cloudtrail action, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-logging-using-cloudtrail.html, it doesn't include anything for consume/retrieve action.

What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudTrial does not support [data events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/logging-data-events-with-cloudtrail.html) for SQS. Similarly SQS APi calls monitoring [does not support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-logging-using-cloudtrail.html) GetMessages calls. So you can't retrospectively check that. You need a full custom solution for that. Namely, you clients which read the SQS must log their own activity.